# can I use a store from a $lib file in svelte?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a `$lib/dates.ts` file which exports some date formatting functions.

The `__layout.svelte` sets the users locale in `userLocale` from the `$store/auth.ts` file.

Inside my `dates.ts` I want to access the `$userLocale` property but I get an error that `$userLocale` is not defined.

Is there someway to use a store inside a $lib file without having to pass it in to function calls?

```
import { userLocale } from '$stores/auth';

export const week = d => new Intl.DateTimeFormat($userLocale, { weekday: 'short' }).format(d);
```

from my component I would do:

`import { week } from '$lib/dates.ts'` and call `week(new Date())`

I really hope I don't have to pass locale to each method call...if I can't use a store inside $lib

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `get` function to read the store values if you don't need a subscription

```js
import { get } from 'svelte/store';

const $userLocale = get(userLocale);
```

note that you should read this value inside your function, otherwise it will always have the initial value and not update when the user changes it.

Do **not** use things from 'svelte/internal' as these are undocumented and can change at any time (unlikely though) without being considered a breaking change.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to use store value inside `$lib/dates.ts` module:

```
import { get_store_value } from 'svelte/internal';

const $userLocale = get_store_value(userLocale);
```